# Get basic information of instagram page

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I have number of instagram pages/urls of different users like https://instagram.com/xxxxx/ etc etc etc. I want to get following information of that page

`name, number of followers, description, bio,`

I have searched and all showing using access token. But I am confused if I will take access token from my account, how can I get information of other pages?

Please guide me how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `access token` to *work* with Instagram API. So if you get an `access token` you can use Instagram API.

To get basic information about a user, use this:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

`{user-id}` is **NOT** username. To get `{user-id}` from username, use this:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]`

To get `access token` use this:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID_HERE]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token
```

And finally the response would be something like:

```
{
    meta: {
        code: 200
    },
    data: {
        username: "lanadelrey",
        bio: "Put not your trust in princes, nor in the son of man, in whom there is no help",
        website: "http://www.lanadelrey.com",
        profile_picture: "https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t51.2885-19/10948781_564619503641170_898618667_a.jpg",
        full_name: "Lana Del Rey",
        counts: {
            media: 114,
            followed_by: 4207076,
            follows: 78
        },
        id: "305506437"
    }
}
```

Comment: @AwaisQarni Yes you can. You just need their `{user-id}`. I explained how to get it.

Comment: This is what exactly I was in need of